# If-Else-Then with today()

Tags: date, if-statement, sas

i am currently trying to write some code that goes through my data and marks a number 0-12 based off the date in the "Week" column. this number appears in a new column called group which is created by the code you see below. The problem is that this column is periods all the way down and not numbers. There are no errors messages in the log so i dont know where i went wrong (im fairly new to sas). PS. the dates range from 6/17 to 9/9

```
data have;
set have;
if today()+84 = Week > today()+79 then group=12;
else if today()+77 = Week > today()+72 then group=11;
else if today()+70 = Week > today()+65 then group=10;
else if today()+63 = Week > today()+58 then group=9;
else if today()+56 = Week > today()+51 then group=8;
else if today()+49 = Week > today()+45 then group=7;
else if today()+42 = Week > today()+37 then group=6;
else if today()+35 = Week > today()+30 then group=5;
else if today()+28 = Week > today()+23 then group=4;
else if today()+21 = Week > today()+16 then group=3;
else if today()+14 = Week > today()+11 then group=2;
else if today()+7  = Week > today()+2 then group=1;
else if today()    = Week > today()-5 then group=0;
run;
```

update: 
the first column is called week and is a monday date that goes 12 weeks into the future. the rest of the columns are variables that i will end up summing based on the group that row is in.

ex:

```
  week       ID var2 ... var18
    17jun2019 1    x        x   
    24jun2019 1    x        x
```

and it continues until 09sept2019.. it does this for each ID (roughly 10,000 of them) but not every id goes 12 weeks out thats why i am using the else if

i would like it to look like

```
   week      ID var2 ... var18 group
    17jun2019 1    x        x    0
    24jun2019 1    x        x    1
    01july2019 1   x        x    2
```

Comment: What is the test you are trying to do?  Your expression is syntactically valid, that is why you are not getting error messages.  But it really looks like gibberish with both an equal sign and a greater than sign without any parentheses to group what is being compared to what and no connections between the two, such as AND or OR.

Comment: Please show an example of your data as it exists, and what you would like it to look like afterwards.

Comment: If I'm reading this right you're comparing if  the outcome of "today()+84 = Week"  which is 0 or 1 is greater than "today()+79" which is 21798.

Comment: Tom, i updated my code. i want it to show that if the current date is the monday of the current we we are in (starting sunday) it outputs a 0 in the group column. If it its the week before the dated monday i want it to output a 1 and so forth. For instance, today is friday so 6/17 (this week's monday) would output a 0 where as 6/24 (this next monday) would output a 1

Comment: Are you just trying to recreate the INTCK() function?

Comment: maybe, just did a quick google of that function as im not too familiar with it. It seems the problem with that function is its not dynamic. My data is updated every monday to replace the past monday and add a future one

Comment: It's easy to fix your code but your approach is too complicated  here. It looks like your'e trying to group dates based on some logic? Is that correct? If so, what's the logic? I suspect a custom format or use of INTNX() or INTCK() or even the WEEK() function may be more efficient. And simpler to maintain.

Comment: in a way yes, i have data that is sorted by ID so each ID has x weeks corresponding to it in numerical order. There are 10,000 IDs and they all have a different number of weeks for instance most are set for 12 weeks out but some may be a little as 1 week out. i want to put each week into a group so that i can eventually sum groups 1-3 4-6 7-9 etc for ID

Comment: So it sounds like you do not what to generate a week number that is based on the day the code was run but based on some baseline date that is different for each ID? Please show example data with the result for that sample data.

Comment: What are you summing?  Is there some other numeric variable you haven't mentioned?  Or are you just counting how many observations per group (week number) ?

Answer (score 1):

A full reference to SAS operators can be found in SAS help by searching `SAS Operators in Expression`.  SAS expressions can use some operators that are relatively unique across the spectrum of coding languages.  Here are some that are not typically found in newly coded SAS (at time of this post)

- `<>` MAX operator
- `><` MIN operator
- **implied** `AND` operator

> Two comparisons with a common variable linked by AND can be condensed with an implied AND.

So the uninitiated readers of the question may misunderstand

```
… 
if today()+35 = Week > today()+30 then group=5;
…
```

as incorrect, instead of recognizing it as an **implied AND**

```
… 
if today()+35 = Week   AND   Week > today()+30 then group=5;
…
```

When syntactically correct, the `=` in the **`implied AND`** causes the expression to be true only on equality.  The week value in [open interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)) ( today()+35, today()+34 ) will never evaluate as true in the above expression.  This is the likely cause of the missing values (`.`) you are seeing.

- Why does the code exhibit non-static delta of 7 in the sequence `30,23,16,11,2,-5` ?
- Should it be `30,23,16,9,2,-5`.
- In other words why is group 1 apparently shooting for a 5 day range [+7, +2) when all the others are 3, such as [+14, +11) ?
- Why are there 2-days domains, presumed weekends, in which group is not assigned, and would thus be missing (`.`) ?

This type of wallpaper code is often better represented by a an arithmetic expression.

For example, presuming integer SAS date values:

```
group = ifn ( MOD (week-today(), 7) in (1,2)
            , .
            , CEIL (week-today() / 7 )
            );

if not ( 0 <= group <= 12 ) then group = .; * probably dont want this but makes it compliant with OP;
```

Tomorrow the group value *could* 'wrong' because it is today() based.  Consider coding a **view** instead of creating a permanent data set -- OR -- place meta information in the variable name `group_on_20190622 = …`

If you insist on wallpaper, consider using a `select` statement which is less prone to typing errors that can happen with errant semi-colons or missing elses.

Answer (score 1):

It is not at all clear what you are trying to do.  It sounds a little like you want to group observations based on how many weeks the date variable (called WEEK) is away from today's date.  It might be easiest to just use the INTCK() function. That will count how many week boundary's are crossed between the two dates.

```
data have ;
  input id week date9.;
  format week date9.;
cards;
1 17jun2019
1 24jun2019
1 01jul2019
2 24jun2019
2 01jul2019
2 08jul2019
;

data want ;
 set have;
 group = intck('week',today(),week);
run;
```

You can then summarize the number of ID's per group.

```
proc freq data=want;
  tables group;
run;
```

Results:

```
The FREQ Procedure

                                  Cumulative    Cumulative
group    Frequency     Percent     Frequency      Percent
----------------------------------------------------------
   -1           1       16.67             1        16.67
    0           2       33.33             3        50.00
    1           2       33.33             5        83.33
    2           1       16.67             6       100.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming week is date and not datetime.

```
data test;
do i = 1 to 30;
 dt = intnx('day',today(),1*i);
 output;
end;
format dt date9.;
run;


data test2;
set test;
if dt ge today() and dt le today()+7 then dt2 = 1;
else if dt ge today()+8 and dt le today()+14 then dt2 = 2;
else if dt ge today()+15 and dt le today()+21 then dt2 = 3;
else if dt ge today()+22 and dt le today()+28 then dt2 = 4;
else if dt ge today()+29 and dt le today()+35 then dt2 = 5;
/* another way */
dt3 = ceil(intck('day',today(),dt)/7); 
run;
```

- removed wrong answer.

Comment: tried this but now im getting an error on each "is" saying its expecting an arithmetic operator. syntax error, statement will be ignored

Comment: You cannot use BETWEEN in and IF statement.  You can use it in a WHERE clause (or in SQL code).  But even then `is` is not part of the syntax.  You could use `where week between today()+79 and today()+84` or `if today()+79 <= week <= today()+84`.

Comment: tom, i tried your first suggestion using the where clause and deleted the then statement as well so ```where week is between today()+79 and today()+84 then group=12:``` but no group column even showed up using this. I am not familiar with adding columns in sas. Thanks again for your help btw

Comment: `if (today() + 79) <= week <= (today() + 84) then group = 12;` Is likely what you mean?

Comment: update: had accidentally changed some formatting in my code but changed it back and your idea works perfectly. thanks a ton. Also thanks to everyone who helped. I learned parenthesis can make or break your code.

Comment: @Tom, Please update your answer, according your comments. Future users of our knowlege base will appreciate they don't have to read the comments to find out what is correct.

Comment: There is no `THEN` clause on a `WHERE` statement. It is for subsetting data only.